# asp:DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

The following code works except the dropdown list is not returned to its original value when the validation fails any ideas?

```
 <tr><td valign="top" style="padding-right: 10px;">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Select Account:</b>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="m_lstAccounts" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"  ValidationGroup="Group1" 
                            CssClass="dropdownList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnAccountChange" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                            <br />
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function ConfirmDropDownValueChange(source, arguments) {
                                if (document.all("AccountProfileDirty").value == "1") {
                                    arguments.IsValid = confirm("Are you sure you want to continue with out saving?");
                                    source.
                                }
                                else {
                                    arguments.IsValid = true;
                                }
                            } 
                        </script> 
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="ConfirmDropDownValidator" runat="server" 
                            ClientValidationFunction="ConfirmDropDownValueChange" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Group1"  /> </td> </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the random `source.` in the middle of your ConfirmDropDownValueChange() function? That would certainly make JavaScript fail.

Comment: I was looking for an answer by bringing up the inteli sence that is not part of the working code sorry for the confusion